# What is $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)}}{\arctan{x}}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I first applied the L'Hôpital's rule to get:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\dfrac{1}{1+\dfrac{1}{x}}\left(-\dfrac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\dfrac{1}{1+x^2}}$$
Simplifying:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}-\dfrac{1+x^2}{x^2+x}$$
Applying L'Hôpital's rule two more times:
$$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}-\dfrac{2}{2}=-1$$
But the answer in my book is just $1$, and graphically, the solution seems to be $1$ as well. How?

Comment: $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\arctan(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: You can't apply L'Hopital's Rule in the first step because $\lim_{x\to\infty}\arctan x=\frac{\pi}2$.

Comment: The correct answer is $0$ and not $1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limit of the bottom half as $x\to\infty$ is $\frac\pi2$, so you cannot apply l'Hôpital's (which requires $\frac00$ or $\frac\infty\infty$ forms).

Indeed, because the denominator is $\pi/2$ in the limit and the numerator's limit is $0$, the overall limit is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

$\ln \left (1+\frac{1}{x} \right )\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$. The quantity $\arctan x$ is bounded as $x\to\infty$. Thus, the limit is zero.